# import css file from node modules using css module in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, node-modules, css-modules

I am using `react-cropper` for including a cropper interface in my project.  I am facing a problem with importing the styles into the component. As per the documentation, `import 'cropperjs/dist/cropper.css';` should do the job. But I am using css modules in my project. ie. `import classes from './style.scss';` and use it like `<div className={classes['image-cropper-wrap']}>`.

I doubt the the problem is because of css modules. I am really not sure how to import `cropper.css` from node modules using css module.

I tried importing the style file like using css module like `import cropperStyles from 'cropperjs/dist/cropper.css';`. It didn't work.

I then tried moving `cropper.css` to the public folder and loading it in `index.html` like `<link rel="stylesheet" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/cropper.css">`. It worked perfectly. But it is not the right way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

i use react-crop and it worked
i imported the css file like this

```
import ReactCrop from "react-image-crop";
import "react-image-crop/dist/ReactCrop.css";

class Avatar extends Component{...

 onImageLoaded = image => {
        this.imageRef = image;
    };

 onCropComplete = crop => {
        this.makeClientCrop(crop);
    };

 render() {...

      <ReactCrop
         src={this.state.src}
         crop={this.state.crop}
         onChange={crop => this.setState({ crop })}
         onImageLoaded={this.onImageLoaded}
         onComplete={this.onCropComplete}
      />
 ....
        }

}
```